# Joining two fields after calculating?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, statistics

I have been working with two layers and I am trying to join them and turn them into a raster data. The first layer is a watershed layer which I have assigned each shed a location from the center point (green dot) for instance shed 1,2,3, and so on. The second layer is distance rings which have a certain distance from the center point. I joined them using the Union tool. After, I use the Calculate Field tool to assign probability to each polygon. For intance if a polygon is located on the first water shed and is on the 1.3 mile distance ring it gets a probability of 7.042 and so on.

Now what I am having trouble with is working with the Summary statistics tool and the Join tool. By using the summary statistics tool I am trying to find the total area that each colored section has. For instance to find the total area of the yellow polygons or the total area of the orange polygons and so on. I am doing this because I want to be able to divide a single polygon that is located on the same colored section by that colors area. For instance the area of the top left yellow colored polygon by the entire area of the yellow colored section. I figured the summary statistics tool would be able to give me that information.

Then by using the Join Field tool I would like to be able to join that area with the statistics that I assigned it before with the Calculate Field tool.

How do I get the two to join?

I have provided two images of my watershed and distance rings united and the modelbuilder model

[image: ModelBuilder Model][image: Watershed and Distance United]

Comment: I would use dissolve directly on your result, you can summarize during the dissolve.

Comment: Why don't you do it step by step?
After you Calculate your `probalily` you `Add Field` and then do the `Summary Statistics`?
If that does not work, can you give us a screentshot of your attributetable after you add the first field?

Comment: You need to set the two inputs of the join as prerequisites to said join.  Otherwise ModelBuilder might not run to the point where you get both inputs and the model will give you garbage results or an error.